# Travel direction of lightning

Tags: lightning

Is it possible to know whether a lightning bolt travel from the ground to the sky or from the sky to the ground?

Alternatively, it could be both sides approaching

Comment: I believe the earth is positively charged in comparison to the clouds - or conversely the clouds are negatively charged compared to the ground. So I'd say the electron current always comes down from the sky. Maybe this wikipage could help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning#Discharge.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/55340/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 6):

Yes it is: [lightning in slow-mo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JVXy-ZqqZ-g)
In general, both are possible, see: [types of lightning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning#Types)

Comment: that's one of my favorite youtube videos.